# fetching taxonomy tree from database from query

Tags: taxonomy-terms, database

I add a vocablary named "product sub categories" and I want to fetch the whole tree structure from datebase through query? Can anybody can help me?

Answer (score 0):

This is a way to do it!

```
$vocabulary = taxonomy_vocabulary_machine_name_load('Services');
$terms = entity_load('taxonomy_term', FALSE, array('vid' => $vocabulary->vid));
```

Comment: Thanku for your reply fons, for this first I have to make connection to a database on a page where I want to display my taxonomy tree?

Comment: Thanku, I did it through below code `$voc =taxonomy_vocabulary_machine_name_load('product_sub_categories');
$tree = taxonomy_get_tree($voc->vid,0,NULL,TRUE);
foreach ($tree as $key => $term){
 print $term->name."</br>";
}`